# Wide Characters not printing while using Ncurses (C++)

Tags: c++, c++14, ncurses, extended-ascii, widechar

The below code fails to print the wide character:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void){
  initscr();
  printw("█");
  getch();
  endwin();
}
```

This code seems to work on some computers and not others, although all the libraries are installed correctly.
(The terminal is capable of displaying extended char!)

I compiled this using:

```
g++ -std=c++14 widechartest.cpp -o widechar -lncursesw
```

Could somebody let me know what the problem is?
Thanks 8)

Comment: What happens if you use the corresponding escape sequence (`\u2588`) instead of embedding the character into your source code?

Comment: Why is it `-lncursesw` in your compilation command and not `-lncurses`? Plus I think @Quentin is right, you should be explicit in the special characters you use, because depending on the encoding on the text file your code is in, it cas lead to problems.

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois apparently [*"ncursesw is ncurses + Unicode (UTF8) support"*](https://github.com/openwrt/packages/issues/526).

Comment: @Quentin I get the same issue.  This code compiles and runs correctly on my desktop, but every other machine it fails to display the characters properly.  All installations seem to be identical though...
When on my desktop, I have to compile with `-lncursesw` otherwise I get the issue I am currently having.

Comment: The suggested [link](https://github.com/openwrt/packages/issues/526) isn't helpful, since the two library configurations do behave differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't initialize the locale.  The [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-Initialization) points this out:

> The  library uses the locale which the calling program has initialized.
>   That is normally done with **`setlocale`**:
>
> `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");`
>
> ***If the locale is not initialized, the library assumes  that  characters
>   are  printable  as in ISO-8859-1, to work with certain legacy programs.***
>   You should initialize the locale and not rely on  specific  details  of
>   the library when the locale has not been setup.